# java sending images over http get doesn't work

Tags: java, string, encode, http-get

I'm trying to send png to server using http get request. I'm using code below to to so.
String encoding (on client):

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(chosenFile.getPath()));
String image = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Then I send http get request to server with String image.
Server receive it but I get image that is not the same as one I sent (I can't open one I received). I'm using `URLEncoder.encode(image, "ISO-8859-1")` to encode url for http get request. When I use `URLEncoder.encode(image, "UTF-8")`, the same happens.

Why this doesn't work?
Is there any better way of doing this kind of stuff?

**UPD #0**

Code for sending an image:

```
private void jMenuItem5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
    int choice = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (choice != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
        File chosenFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    try {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(chosenFile.getPath()));
        String image = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");

        if(image != null){
            boolean allsent = false;
            long k = 0;
            String query = "0";
            while(!allsent){
                String s = image;
                String send = "";
                long q;
                if(k+400>image.length()){
                    q=image.length();
                    allsent=true;
                }
                else q = k+400;
                for(long i=k;i<q;i++)
                    send+=s.charAt((int) i);
                System.out.println(send);
                String response = new HTTP().GET(Constants.ADDRESS_ADDIMAGE
                        + "?" + Constants.USERNAME + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + Constants.IMAGE + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(send, "ISO-8859-1")
                        + "&" + Constants.QUERY + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
                k+=400;
                query="1";                            
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Note:**
HTTP().GET() invokes standard http get.

**UPD #1**
Server code

```
@GET
@Path("/addimage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String addImage(@QueryParam("username") String uname, @QueryParam("image") String image, @QueryParam("query") String query) {       
    if(query.equals("0")){
        String s = image;
        JDBC.addImage("ABase", "MarketLogin", "image", uname, s);
    }
    else{
        String s = JDBC.selectDB("ABase", "MarketLogin", "image", uname, "username") + image;
        JDBC.addImage("ABase", "MarketLogin", "image", uname, s);
    }
    return "1";
}
```

**Note:**
JDBC is class for updating mysql DB. Server is expecting String encoded by `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Why send a string? Send bytes.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do so?

Comment: If you're having a problem sending an image, then include the code that sends the image! (not just the code that reads it). Also an Image is very definitely not encoded with "ISO-8859-1"!

Comment: YOu need to send the content as a mime-type that is correct for the image you are sending. It's not a String, and attempting to treat it as one will never work.

Comment: We need to know more about what the web server is expecting. From your code, it seems to be expecting the image data as an encoded string in a query parameter. This is possibly true, but very, very, odd. So point us at the definition of how that web server wants images

Comment: HTTP GET is used for small data. For large data such images it's better to use POST

Comment: Server is expecting image as Constants.IMAGE, as you can see, it is divided in packages for size reasons. It must be encoded in some way, but any of these 2 that I mentioned are destroying image data.

Comment: I'll replace this later with HTTP POST but how can I solve problem of sending images?

Comment: We have no idea what the server is expecting as the encoding of images so we have no idea why your code isn't working. You've not told us what the value of "Constants.IMAGE" is, and in any case, it's only a keyword in the query string

Comment: Basically, you have a custom server implementation, but you've not shown us the code that handles the image data (JDBC.addImage). How do you expect us to work out what's wrong?

Comment: Does it work for very small images (that can be sent in one request)?

Comment: Client sends string query (if query = 0 then it rewrites image, otherwise it appends incoming string), so everything here works except the image string given to server. It is supposed to be encoded in ISO-8859-1 but it isn't as it is received on server (it changes after http request)

Comment: It can work with large images, but I will replace it with POST method after solving encoding problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and sending bytes instead of strings.

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(bytes); // your bytes here         
    baos.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
}
finally {
    if(baos != null)
       baos.close();
    if(osw != null)
       osw.close();
    if(connection != null)
       connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Can you just explain what does `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");` mean?

Comment: Method `setRequestProperty` is  for setting some general request property. Here a content-type is specified, though try without it, if the server accepts it.